# I need that these header_top will be hidden at start of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, styling

I need that these header_top will be hidden at start of page, please help

```
    var header_top = jQuery('#header-top-wrapper');
       var header_top_button = jQuery('#header-wrapper a.accordion').addClass('active');
       var header_top_height = header_top.height();
       header_top_button.click(function() {
      if(header_top_button.hasClass('active')) {
        header_top_button.removeClass('active');
        header_top.css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
        header_top.stop(true, false).animate({"height": "0px"}, 500, function(){
      });      
      }
      else {
         header_top.stop(true, false).animate({"height": header_top_height + "px"}, 500,         function(){
        header_top_button.addClass('active');
        header_top.css({'overflow': 'visible'});
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to add a css style:

```
#header-top-wrapper {
     display:none;
}
```

and then show it with javascript

Comment: yeah, whenever you want to show it you would could just do:

`$("#header-top-wrapper").show();` or `$("#header-top-wrapper").fadeIn();`